# Can you combine replace_html with a visual_effect in Rails RJS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, scriptaculous

I'm developing a website with Ruby on Rails and I have a div with some content.  After clicking a link I want that content to get replaced with some other stuff.  This works fine with replace_html and rjs.

However, I'd prefer there to be a slight fade/appear (crossfade?) transition between the old and new content.  Also the div will be resized a bit so it'd be cooler if this did a grow/shrink effect.  I was thinking Scriptaculous must have something like this built in, but I sure can't find it if they do.

By the way there is a great example of this if you have a Basecamp account: login and click "All people" then "Add a new company" to see the effect in action.

Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To crossfade, you need to position your new content absolutely, and with the same x/y coordinates as the old content. Here's a tested example:

```
page.insert_html :after, 'old-content', content_tag('p', '[new content]', :id => 'new-content', :style => 'display:none')
page << <<-JS
  var oldOffset = $('old-content').cumulativeOffset();
  $('new-content').setStyle({
    position: 'absolute',
    left:     oldOffset.left + 'px',
    top:      oldOffset.top + 'px'
  });
JS
page['old-content'].fade :duration => 3
page['new-content'].appear :duration => 3
```

Note the big block in the middle—some things are easier in Prototype than in RJS.

Comment: This definitely does the crossfade I was looking for - thanks Ron!  Best answer so far.  The resize still jumps instead of growing/shrinking smoothly.  I'm guessing some more prototype would be needed to get the width & height of the old vs new and do a grow or shrink at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A strategy could be to put the element in a wrapping div, fade out that wrapping div, replace the HTML in the element, and then fade in the wrapping div again.

I'm not a RJS/scriptaculous user myself, so I'm not sure what the code is, but I'm pretty sure that strategy will work.

Comment: Hi leethal...thanks for the response.  Doing the fade out/fade in sequentially prob won't work.  The page will jump (resizing) as the first one disappears and second reappears just after.  Also this doesn't do the resizing.  I suspect they are doing something more advanced on the basecamp example.

Answer (score 0):

Fade out the 1st div.
Blind in the 2nd div at the same time.
As the 1st one fades, the 2nd will appear to expand what's left of the first one.

Well, something like that.

Load up Firebug and step through the code if you want to see what they're calling.

Comment: Is there a way to do it at the same time?  I thought it would be sequential.  Good idea on the firebug though.

Comment: Whoops..I was mistaken.  They do happen at the same time!  Sorry about that.  It still jumps after fade out though.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way would be to do the replace and then pulsate the div.